# Из windows нет доступа к расшаренным папкам Solaris

Tags: samba, solaris, linux

Папка расшарена через sharesmb=on. Сервер самбы включен.

Теперь папка из винды видна по сети в виде пул_папка, но доступа к ней нет по-прежнему. Пишет ошибку, что нет прав.

Видимо, копать надо в сторону настроек самбы и pam, но документация у оракла устаревшая.

Может, кто знает?

Answer (score 2):

Логи. Для начала смотрите логи. Возможна проблема с правами на fs.